# Zend framework user interaction

Tags: php, zend-framework2, user-input, zend-form, confirmation

This is my html view file:

```
<?php foreach($this->application as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['APPID'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['APPNAME'];?></td>
```

">DELETE

This my zend framework controller `deleteAction`:

```
public function deleteAction()
{   
    $form = new ApplicationForm();
    $form->submit->setlabel('Delete');
    $this->view->form = $form;

    $ID = $this->_getParam('ID', 0);  

    $delete_app = new Application()
    $delete_app->deleteApp($ID);
    $this->_helper->redirector('index');                                            
}
```

Currently my delete action is working fine. Now before the delete is executed I want to add a user confirmation with `yes | no` options.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check [this example from the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html#deleting-an-album)

Comment: You can use javascript on button click

Comment: Thanks Niketan, I used javascript onclick input button type.

Comment: Did you check that example? That is the preferred way of implementing such solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can add a pop-up box:

```
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'))
{
    window.location = "<?php echo $this->url('delete', array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $example->getId())) ?>"
}
```

See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991035/how-to-use-zend-delete-action-in-confirmation-popup).

Comment: Hi Tibsar, 
Thanks for the reply. 
could you please tell where i can above code.

Comment: This is my View file
<?php foreach($this->application as $Apps): ?>

<tr>
 
 <td><?php echo $Apps['APPID'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $Apps['APPNAME'];?></td>
 
 <td>
   
   <a href="/admin/app/edit?ID=<?php echo $Apps['ID'];?>">EDIT</a>
   <a href="/admin/app/delete?ID=<?php echo $Apps['ID'];?>">DELETE</a>
  
 </td>
  
</tr>

Comment: @user6420577 Can you add the code for your view to your question? It's difficult to read in the comment